# SLOW QUERY / IN HAVING Clause

Tags: mysql, performance, having, database-indexes

I have a many-to-many relationship database in **MySQL**

[image: mysql_database_structure]

And this **Query**:

```
SELECT main_id FROM posts_tag
    WHERE post_id IN ('134','140','187')
    GROUP BY main_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) = 3
```

There are **~5,300,000** rows into this table and that query seems to be slow like **5 seconds** (and slower if I add more ids into search)

I want to ask if there is any way to make it faster?

EXPLAIN shows this: [image: mysql_query]

By the way, I want to add more conditions like NOT IN and possible JOIN new tables which has same structure but different data. Not so much like this but first I want to know if there is any way to make that simple query faster?

Any advice would be helpful, even another method, or structure etc.

PS: Hardware is Intel Core i9 3.6Ghz, 64GB RAM, 480GB SSD. So I think the server specs is not a problem.

Comment: It's not slow, your query seems to return 78003 rows, which is a lot. Is that the expected result?

Comment: Basically not, without EXPLAIN it returns only 64 rows which is expected result. I don't really know why shows those 78003. Probably that's how much is checking...

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE posts_tag; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'posts_tag';  for analysis.

Comment: @alexfsk The 78003 in your EXPLAIN is the number of 'rows examined' to return your SELECTion.

Comment: @WilsonHauck A) https://prnt.sc/1rdt264 B) https://prnt.sc/1rdsnxf

Comment: @alexfsk - Those constraints look terrible; check the table references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "composite" and "covering" index:

```
INDEX(post_id, main_id)
```

And get rid of `INDEX(post_id)` since it will then be redundant.

"Covering" helps speed up a query.

Assuming this is a normal **"many-to-many"** table, then:

```
CREATE TABLE post_main (
    post_id -- similar to `id` in table `posts`
    main_id -- similar to `id` in table `main`
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id, main_id),
    INDEX(main_id, post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There is no need for `AUTO_INCREMENT` anywhere in a many-to-many table.

(You could add FK constraints, but I say 'why bother'.)

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

**And NOT IN**

This gets a bit tricky.  I think this is one way; there may be others.

```
SELECT  main_id
    FROM post_main
    WHERE post_id IN (244,229,193,93,61)
    GROUP BY main_id AS x
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM post_main
                  WHERE main_id = x.main_id
                    AND post_id IN (92,10,234) );
```

Comment: Rick,  Please check the posted SHOW CREATE TABLE for posts_tag and to me it looks like alexfsk will need to keep his INDEX(post_id) because it is used to manage a CONSTRAINT.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Ouch!  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Rick, Trying to keep everything hanging together.  Just happened to notice the usefulness of the column with the CONSTRAINT.  Thanks for all you do for the community.

Comment: I tried that structure from the example and it was speed up a lot. Could anyone show me how i can filter by NOT in same query? 

SELECT main_id FROM posts_tag
    WHERE post_id IN (134,140,187) AND post_id NOT IN (23,50,301,88,941)
    GROUP BY main_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) = 3

And how i can join a new table with same structure on this Query? Thanks!

Comment: @alexfsk - Are you sure of that query?  If post_id is one of 134,140,187 then it can't be in the other list.  What is the goal of that query?  (Express in words, not SQL.)

Comment: @alexfsk - Consider starting a new question to discuss `NOT`.

Comment: @RickJames ea i am sure, i want to filter main ids which contains those post_id from IN and NOT contains those post_id from NOT IN. Here is an example in my screeenshot https://prnt.sc/1rhwl46. Let's say 694352 it is main_id, and the other ones are post_id. Here are 244,229,193 etc as u see in screenshot. For this example the query would be: SELECT main_id FROM posts_tag WHERE post_id IN (244,229,193,93,61) AND post_id NOT IN (92,10,234) GROUP BY main_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) = 5 In this case the 694352 it would be displayed as long 92,10,234 are not in the table.

Comment: @RickJames If instead of 92,10,234 i would say 92,54 main_id 694352 it shouldn't be displayed because post_id 54 is into NOT clause and is into the table. I want to make a tag filter function and i want to filter posts by choosen tags (like good tags and bad tags) and the query needs to belong to that.

Comment: @alexfsk - OK.  You are looking for `main_ids` that have _all_ of the "IN" numbers associated with it, but _none_ of the "NOT IN" numbers.

Comment: @alexfsk - I added a possible solution.

Comment: @RickJames I tried your solution and it's still slow. I didn't even joined a new table to that query beacause it would be much slower. I created a new post here with different details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134340/mysql-query-performance-and-optimization

Answer (score 0):

Alexfsk, your Query on the second line has the IN variables surrounded by single quotes.  When your column name is defined as INT or mediumint (or any kind of int) datatype, adding the single quotes around the data causes datatype conversion delays on every row considered and delays completion of your query.