# MYSQL Query Performance and Optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `seo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tags_table_one` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tags_table_three` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tags_table_two` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

After adding data to this tables:

- **posts** (~ **500k** rows)
- **tags** (~ **30k** rows)
- **tags_table_one** (~ **5 milions** rows)
- **tags_table_two** (~ **700k** rows)
- **tags_table_three** (~ **800k** rows)

This is the Query i tried which works but it is slow:

```
SELECT p.title
FROM   `tags_table_one` x
       JOIN `posts` p
         ON x.post_id = p.id
WHERE  `tag_id` IN ( 244, 229, 193, 93 )
GROUP  BY `post_id`
HAVING Count(*) = 4
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   `tags_table_one`
                       WHERE  `post_id` = x.post_id
                              AND `tag_id` IN ( 92, 10, 234 ))
```

My goal is to make a search filter by tags (good and bad tags). For example let's say I have as **good tags** `"244","229","193","93"` and as bad tags `"92","10","234"`. I need a **MYSQL** Query to filter those posts by specified tags. The result should return all posts which has **all good tags mentioned** and **NOT all bad tags mentioned** (so it should contains ALL not just some). The thing is, good and bad tags can be choosen from any tags_table so i think it needs a JOIN or something like that which i didn't added to my query because i don't know exactly how to. I tried before and i got a bad result maybe because a lot of records into tables (In some cases, queries took over 30-40 seconds which is too much time to execute). With a few records works fast but i don't need that. I need an optimised Database / Query to make it as fast as possible. If you have any examples of databases / queries would be great to try. Even if there is any changes to MYSQL config or something I'm glad to hear.

**EDIT:**

The EXPLAIN of Query:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I moved all entire data to one table with a type column and now i have the table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags_table_one` (
 `post_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `tag_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`tag_id`,`type`),
 KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`,`post_id`,`type`),
 KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

according @RickJames solution but now i have the following Query:

```
SELECT posts.id AS id,
       posts.title
FROM   `tags_table_one`
       INNER JOIN posts
               ON tags_table_one.post_id = posts.id
WHERE  ( `tag_id` IN ( 15, 25, 16, 17,
                       234, 14, 9 )
         AND `type` = 1 )
       AND ( `tag_id` IN ( 81, 48, 56 )
             AND `type` = 2 )
       AND posts.active = '1'
GROUP  BY `post_id`
HAVING Count(*) = "7"
```

So let's say i have tags `15, 25, 16, 17, 234, 14, 9` with `type 1` and tags `81, 48, 56` with `type 2`. I want to return all posts which contains all tags mentioned for type 1 and type 2. If anyone could show me an example of Query with NOT IN would be great because i need that too. So that would be for bad tags.

At this moment, that query doesn't return any result for me. It does only if i remove the `AND (` tag_id`IN ( 81, 48, 56 ) AND`type `= 2 )` part from the Query but is not what i wanted because isn't filtering properly.

**EDIT 3**

I tried to manage it but i got only this unworking Query:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title
FROM `posts` p
INNER JOIN tags_table_one t1 ON p.id=t1.post_id
INNER JOIN tags_table_one t2 ON p.id=t2.post_id
INNER JOIN tags_table_one t3 ON p.id=t3.post_id
WHERE p.active='1'
  AND t1.tag_id IN (15, 25, 16, 17, 234, 14, 9) AND t1.type = '1'
  AND t2.tag_id IN (81, 48, 56) AND t2.type = '2'
  AND t3.tag_id IN (47, 51, 355, 71) AND t3.type = '3'
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(t1.tag_id) = 7
AND
HAVING COUNT(t2.tag_id) = 3
AND
HAVING COUNT(t3.tag_id) = 4
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

The problem is with "**HAVING COUNT**", if i remove that it works but it doesn't filter.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is unclear to me what you are asking us to help you with! If you need help in speeding up an existing query, then we need to know what the query is, some sample data, expected results, detailed table definitions including all indexes and the output of explain on your query. If you need help with database design, then you need to understand that we can help with generic concepts, such as how to model a many-to-many relationship. We cannot really help you designing a database for you as it requires deep understanding of your data, your business requirements, and your business

Comment: Three different tag tables seems like a mistake.

Comment: @ysth It's not a mistake because each tag table it has different data which i don't want to be in one table.

Comment: @Shadow I edited my post with some detailed database structure & query i tried.

Comment: post id and tag id fields are not indexed, meaning your query has to use a full table scan. I would also combine three tags tables together and use a 4th field to distinguish between the 3 types - but this is where not knowing your business or your business requirements kick in

Comment: @Shadow It works slow even if i add indexes on post id and tag id. I used different tags table just not to have all records into one table but maybe i can try ur suggestion. And about indexes it works slow anyway. Probably i didn t added them properly. Can you show me an example how u would add them to these tables? Thanks!

Comment: Consider one table with the name or id for filtering, with a type column indicating which of three child tables will have the additional data

Comment: You say it works slow.  Show output of `explain` for the slow query

Comment: @ysth When i tried that Query on that table with 5 million records, i got results but took very long time to execute. What about if i combine all data to one table, it will be over 10 millions probably. It doesn t affect performance in any way? Also i used indexes but didn’t made too much. Probably i didn t added them properly or i don’t know…

Comment: @alexfsk we do not know what indexes you added (the create table statements in the question list primary keys only). We do not know what the explain says after adding the indexes. 10 million records is not particularly much nowadays for a modern rdbms. Obviously, if you are running your mysql on a raspberry PI, that may struggle with it, but a proper laptop / desktop / server will not.

Comment: please update your question to show output of `EXPLAIN SELECT p.title
FROM...rest of your query`

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want with the multiple tag tables.  are you only ever going to hit one of them in a given query?  if not, please add some examples of specific queries you want to do

Comment: "Not all" means "some is OK".  Perhaps you mean "none of" the 3 bad tags?  Clarification of this is critical to writing the correct SQL.

Comment: @ysth Added EXPLAIN SELECT p.title FROM...

Comment: @RickJames "Not all" means "all mentioned not just some". I mean it need to remove from the results all posts which has those bad tags mentioned in query.

Comment: you are still being ambiguous.  remove from the results all posts that have all those bad tags or remove from the results all posts that have any of those bad tags?

Comment: @ysth Yes, remove from the results all posts that have all those bad tags. And for the good ones needs to be the same thing: keep on the results all posts that have all those good tags.

Comment: @alexfsk - The Explain implies that much of the table has those 4 tag_ids.  What percentage of the table is that?

Comment: @RickJames https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeJvt.png

Comment: @alexfsk - Re Edit 3:  With the HAVINGs, the query should return posts with all 14 tags.  Without the HAVINGs, the query should return posts with _any_ (one or more) tag(s) of the 7 type 1 tags and also have any of the 3 type-2's and any of the 4 type-3's.  (That implies at least 3 (one of each type) tags will match.)

Comment: @alexfsk - Note that `HAVING .. = 0` would let you _exclude_ a set of tags -- that is fetch posts that do _not_ include the indicated tags.

Comment: @RickJames The thing is this query doesn't work because it has HAVING twice more after the first one. The syntax is wrong. If you can please show me an example of my query based on your last edit query. I replied to your answer a bit down.

Comment: @alexfsk - oops, I missed that.  The syntax is `HAVING expr AND expr AND expr`

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `tags_table_one` (
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id),
 INDEX(tag_id, post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Notes:

- Get rid of `id`.
- Make composite indexes going both ways; make one of them the PK.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

`INDEX(post_id), INDEX(tag_id)` would be faster, but still (as you found out) quite slow.

`tags` probably needs `INDEX(name)`?

**After edit**

```
SELECT  posts.id AS id, posts.title
    FROM  `tags_table_one`
    INNER JOIN  posts  ON tags_table_one.post_id = posts.id
    WHERE  `tag_id` IN ( 15, 25, 16, 17, 234, 14, 9 )
      AND  `type` = 1 
      AND  posts.active = '1'
    GROUP BY  `post_id`
    HAVING  Count(*) = "7" 

SELECT  posts.id AS id, posts.title
    FROM  `tags_table_one`
    INNER JOIN  posts  ON tags_table_one.post_id = posts.id
    WHERE  `tag_id` IN ( 81, 48, 56 )
      AND  `type` = 2 
      AND  posts.active = '1'
    GROUP BY  `post_id`
    HAVING  Count(*) = "3"
```

The first of those Selects gives posts with all 7 of those tag_ids.
The second of those Selects gives posts with all 3 of the second set of tag_ids.

Which do you want?

A.  The posts with all 10 tags
B.  The posts with all 7 of the first set, but none of the second
C.  The posts with all 7 of the first set plus some of the second set

We can do a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN...IS NOT NULL` to get (A) or (B).  (C) will take some more fiddling.

Where did `type` come from?  since you are reading from `tags_table_one` in both cases, I guess it is not that "one/two/three"??

**More**

When you say `AND t2.tag_id IN (19, 684) AND t2.type = 2` you are allowing it to have *either* 19 or 684.  But it sounds like you want it to have *both* 19 and 684.  That will require different SQL.

Plan A:  turn that one `JOIN` + `IN` into two `JOINs`.

Plan B:  continue with the `JOIN` + `IN`, but use `HAVING count(*) = 2`.  But this gets messy because you have several such clauses in the same query.

Plan C:  use `GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORDER BY tag_id) = "19,684"` (with the numbers in numerical order).  This has other complexities.

Plan D:  If you always need all of the given tags, then

```
WHERE t1.tag_id IN (15, 223) AND t1.type = 1
  AND t2.tag_id IN (19, 684) AND t2.type = 2
  AND t3.tag_id IN (5) AND t3.type = 4
```

plus

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

might be made to work.

I think that Plan D has the most promise; give it a try.

Comment: I edited my question, i have some problems with queries.

Comment: `type` comes from `tags_table_one` as i moved all data into this table, i made it to filter with 1,2,3 (Instead using multiple tables: tags_table_one = type 1, tags_table_two = type 2, tags_table_three = type 3). I think (A) and (B) it is what i want but `type` needs to belong on each set of tags `( 15, 25, 16, 17, 234, 14, 9 ) AND  type = 1` / `( 81, 48, 56 ) AND  type = 2 `. I need to get posts based on specific `tag_id` and `type`.

Comment: Please don't call it `tags_table_one`; leave off "_one" is is confusing me.

Comment: Are there entries for tag_id=15 for multiple types?  I _really_ need to understand why `type` exists at all.

Comment: Ok, you can remove "_one". The name of the table was remaining the same but i use only one table now. There is no more tables.

Comment: Yes, tag_id=15 could be for multiple types.

Comment: `INDEX(type, tag_id)` is important for performance.

Comment: @alexfsk - This question is getting unwieldy.  Please start a new Question with one tags_table, shorter lists in the HAVINGs, _and example data_ that show both sample source data and desired results.  A dozen or so rows of data might suffice to show both rows that you want to fetch and rows that you want to _not_ fetch.

Comment: I started a new question but it was closed as duplicated, idk why. Check out this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6780/8 `Post title 2` and `Post title 3` doesn't have `tag_id 684` AND `type 2` and doesn't need to be returned.

Comment: fiddle:  Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Comment: Linke to new question?

Comment: This is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183157/mysql-query-where-in-clause but it redirects me automatically on another old question of someone else. I put it on the another fiddle site. Check this if you can see it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Cknc8kmb8gmVyJbWkdVj3/0

Comment: @alexfsk - Thanks.  I'll look into that dubious "dup".  Meanwhile, please provide (perhaps in comments in the fiddle) the desired output.  I'm not sure we have finished the discussion of "all of" vs "some of" vs "any of" vs "none of".

Comment: I updated fiddle. Check it out here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Cknc8kmb8gmVyJbWkdVj3/7

Comment: @alexfsk - I added to my Answer.  (As I suspected, there was a semantic issue with `IN` meaning `any of`, not `all of`.)

Comment: I was trying Plan D and returned 0 results. I don't know exactly if `HAVING COUNT(*) = 5` it works for all of the given tags. Seems not for me. Could u just edit the fiddle with any working query? Could be A, B, C or D. I don't mind. I just want to have them filtered but also i want the fastest way to execute the query. I don't want a slow one. Thanks for helping me! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Cknc8kmb8gmVyJbWkdVj3/8

Comment: (1, 15, 1) is not in the table, hence post_id=1 does not belong in the ouput.

Comment: I put `(1, 15, 1)` into the table and seems doesn't return anything. I made another test here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Cknc8kmb8gmVyJbWkdVj3/12 . Do you know why doesn't show the post since it's matching all tags? I don't know really how that `HAVING COUNT` works. I choosed to use `=` instead of `IN` for single tags. I put `HAVING COUNT(*) = 5` because there are 3 tags separated with comma for `t1` and 2 tags separated with comma for `t3` . I need to know exactly how that count it's calculated to build the correct query?

Comment: Did you checked my last fiddle? I still didn't manage it :( I need to know how that having count works for those sets of tags..