# MYSQL Query WHERE IN Clause

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6780/8

I want to filter by specific `tag_id` and `type` but this query returns wrong data. It should return only `Post title 1` which has `t1.tag_id IN (15, 223) AND t1.type = 1 AND t2.tag_id IN (19, 684) AND t2.type = 2 AND t3.tag_id IN (5) AND t3.type = 4`.

`Post title 2` and `Post title 3` doesn't have `tag_id 684` AND `type 2` and doesn't need to be returned.

Query:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title
FROM `posts` p
INNER JOIN tags_table t1 ON p.id=t1.post_id
INNER JOIN tags_table t2 ON p.id=t2.post_id
INNER JOIN tags_table t3 ON p.id=t3.post_id
WHERE 
  t1.tag_id IN (15, 223) AND t1.type = 1
  AND t2.tag_id IN (19, 684) AND t2.type = 2
  AND t3.tag_id IN (5) AND t3.type = 4
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Post title 1'),
(2, 'Post title 2'),
(3, 'Post title 3'),
(4, 'Post title 4'),
(5, 'Post title 5'),
(6, 'Post title 6'),
(7, 'Post title 7'),
(8, 'Post title 8'),
(9, 'Post title 9'),
(10, 'Post title 10');

CREATE TABLE `tags_table` (
 `post_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `tag_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`tag_id`,`type`),
 KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`,`post_id`,`type`),
 KEY `type` (`type`,`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tags_table` (`post_id`, `tag_id`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 2, 6),
(1, 4, 1),
(1, 5, 4),
(1, 5, 5),
(1, 19, 1),
(1, 19, 2),
(1, 36, 2),
(1, 39, 1),
(1, 44, 1),
(1, 57, 4),
(1, 59, 4),
(1, 70, 1),
(1, 71, 1),
(1, 100, 4),
(1, 105, 1),
(1, 115, 1),
(1, 121, 1),
(1, 177, 1),
(1, 193, 1),
(1, 199, 4),
(1, 223, 1),
(1, 225, 1),
(1, 236, 1),
(1, 290, 1),
(1, 326, 1),
(1, 337, 1),
(1, 381, 4),
(1, 426, 1),
(1, 684, 2),
(1, 888, 4),
(1, 926, 2),
(1, 964, 2),
(1, 2111, 4),
(1, 2314, 4),
(1, 2346, 2),
(1, 3303, 4),
(1, 3375, 2),
(1, 3415, 1),
(1, 3692, 4),
(1, 3964, 2),
(1, 4004, 4),
(1, 10151, 4),
(1, 10512, 4),
(1, 14812, 4),
(1, 16204, 4),
(1, 16886, 4),
(1, 17679, 4),
(1, 18266, 4),
(1, 42096, 3 ),
(2, 1, 6),
(2, 2, 4),
(2, 3, 2),
(2, 5, 4),
(2, 15, 1),
(2, 18, 1),
(2, 19, 2),
(2, 35, 1),
(2, 42, 2),
(2, 47, 1),
(2, 50, 1),
(2, 61, 1),
(2, 66, 4),
(2, 93, 2),
(2, 97, 1),
(2, 121, 1),
(2, 148, 1),
(2, 193, 1),
(2, 205, 1),
(2, 223, 1),
(2, 250, 4),
(2, 255, 4),
(2, 268, 4),
(2, 431, 1),
(2, 554, 4),
(2, 632, 4),
(2, 3279, 2),
(2, 3415, 1),
(2, 3530, 2),
(2, 4121, 2),
(2, 11645, 4),
(2, 11646, 4),
(2, 11955, 4),
(2, 13092, 4),
(2, 15427, 4),
(2, 32542, 3),
(3, 1, 6),
(3, 5, 4),
(3, 15, 1),
(3, 19, 2),
(3, 57, 4),
(3, 66, 4),
(3, 77, 4),
(3, 91, 2),
(3, 99, 4),
(3, 196, 4),
(3, 225, 1),
(3, 290, 1),
(3, 303, 1),
(3, 635, 4),
(3, 1243, 4),
(3, 6469, 4),
(3, 16590, 1);
```

**EDIT**

I changed my query with this

```
    SELECT p.id,
       p.title
FROM `posts` p
INNER JOIN tags_table t1 ON p.id=t1.post_id
INNER JOIN tags_table t2 ON p.id=t2.post_id
INNER JOIN tags_table t3 ON p.id=t3.post_id
WHERE 
      t1.tag_id IN ( 15, 223 ) AND t1.type = '1'
      AND t2.tag_id IN ( 19, 684 ) AND t2.type = '2'
       AND t3.tag_id IN ( 5 ) AND t3.type = '4'
    GROUP  BY p.id
    HAVING 
    COUNT(t1.tag_id) = 2 AND
    COUNT(t2.tag_id) = 2 AND 
    COUNT(t3.tag_id) = 1
    ORDER  BY g.id DESC
```

and it doesn't return any post. If i use only `COUNT(t1.tag_id) = 2` it returns but seems again it doesn't filter properly because it doesn't take in consideration:

```
AND t2.tag_id IN ( 19, 684 ) AND t2.type = '2'
           AND t3.tag_id IN ( 5 ) AND t3.type = '4'
```

Comment: Post Title 3 has `tag_id = 19` and `type = 2`.

Comment: `tag_id IN (19, 684)` means it has either of those tags, it doesn't have to have both.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have `tag_id = 684` and `type = 2` . So i don't want to be returned if it doesn't have exactly all the same values i added to the query.